# Does RavenDb's `Include` support constructing a document id, not just selecting one?

Tags: ravendb

This code here is not working as expected. Specifically, it seems the calls to `Include` are not causing any extra documents to be added to the session. Thus, the `Load`s are each costing a full db hit. This is RavenDb 3.5.

I couldn't find examples that actually use `Include` this way. They all seem to emit a "selector" that is used to find a member on the document, and that member holds the literal document id to include. Whereas I am constructing the document id and returning it as a string.

```
session.Query<Coil>()
    .Include(c => nameof(CoilState) + "/" + id)
    .Include(c => nameof(CoilExt) + "/" + id)
    .Include(c => nameof(Material) + "/" + c.MaterialCode)
    .Where(c => c.CoilId == id)
    .ToList()
    .Select(c =>
        Coil_Dto.ToCoilDto(
            c
            , session.Load<CoilState>(nameof(CoilState) + "/" + c.CoilId)
            , session.Load<CoilExt>(nameof(CoilExt) + "/" + c.CoilId)
            , session.Load<Material>(nameof(Material) + "/" + c.MaterialCode)
        )
    )
    .SingleOrDefault()
```

My question is: can `Include` be used in this way? If not, is there some way to achieve that "include" functionality using my constructed ids?

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue for you, Josh? (In particular, use .Lazy instead of .Include?)

Comment: @JudahHimango You confirmed by suspicions about `Include`. I ended up using explicit `Load`s to get child documents, where the set of ids passed to `Load` is projected from the original parent document list. That got me down to 4 db trips. With `Lazy` I could get it down to 2, but performance is adequate at this point.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use Lazy, rather than Include.

---

### Include

The .Include method should be passed the name of a property on your object(s) which contains an ID.

```
// Good:
// Note that StateId, ExtId, and MaterialId are all properties on our Coil class.
session.Query<Coil>()
   .Include(c => c.StateId)
   .Include(c => c.ExtId)
   .Inclide(c => c.MaterialId);

// Bad:
session.Query<Coil>
   .Include(c => "CoilStates/123")
   .Include(c => "CoilExts/456")
   .Include(c => "Materials/789")
```

In short, make sure your .Include calls are passed the **name of properties on the Coil class**. Those properties should contain string values which are IDs of other documents. Then they'll all be loaded in a single trip to the database.

---

### Lazy

If Include doesn't make sense for your scenario, but you still want to load disparate objects in a single DB call, use the [lazy API](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-perform-queries-lazily)

```
// Lazily load the coil. No DB trip yet.
var lazyCoil = session.Query<Coil>()
   .Where(...)
   .Lazily();

// Lazily load a CoilState. No DB trip yet.
var lazyCoilState = session.Advanced.Lazily.Load<CoilState>("CoilStates/123");

// Lazily load a Material. Still no DB trip.
var lazyMaterial = session.Advanced.Lazily.Load<Material>("Materials/456");

// Grab one of the values. This will fetch all lazy loaded items in 1 trip.
var coil = lazyCoil.Value;

// Grab the other values. No DB trip needed; they're already loaded!
var coilState = lazyCoilState.Value;
var material = lazyMaterial.Value;
```